# How we can send the Url Using Http Get Method in Android Android

Tags: android, http, get

How we can send the Url  Using Http Get Method in Android Android ..I tried but it doesn't works.can u give me the code to send url via http get method..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you are trying to download a URL in Android.

Using the standard java http url classes should work for you:

```
final InputStream is = new URL("http://www.google.com/").openStream();
```

If you like, you can then wrap the stream in a BufferedInputStream and DataInputStream to make reading the contents easier.

If you would like more flexibility, you can definitely use [httpclient 4.0](http://hc.apache.org/), which is included in the Android distribution.  There are several [examples](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html) of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client/examples.html

The first example ("Response handling") may fit your needs.